How to use odoo:17 Docker image in devcontainer?
I am trying to create a devcontainer for the development of custom Odoo modules. This devcontainer is based on the official odoo:17 Docker image. You can see the current state of my devcontainer in my-odoo-project.zip. I would like to ask the following questions:

It took me a few days of effort to discover that I needed to add a new user with UID/GID 1000 in the odoo:17 image to make the devcontainer work with this image. See the creation of the developer user in .devcontainer/Dockerfile.fajnodoo17 and the "remoteUser" in .devcontainer/devcontainer.json. Is creating a user with UID/GID 1000 the only solution, or is there a more straightforward alternative?

How can I map the installed Odoo modules (applications) to my devcontainer? Where are they located in the odoo:17 image?

How can I run odoo-bin command in the devcontainer (or Docker container)?

Do you have any other recommendations on how to correctly use the odoo:17 image in a devcontainer for custom Odoo modules development?


